# Laravel create nested select box from joined tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables with associated models in my laravel app: `subsectors` and `sectors`. Here's an example.

Subsectors:

```
|id | name          |sector_id|
|---|---------------|---------|
| 1 | Global Equity | 1       |
| 2 | US Equity     | 1       |
| 3 | UK Equity     | 1       |
| 4 | Govt Bonds    | 2       |
| 5 | IG Bonds      | 2       |
| 6 | HY Bonds      | 2       |
| 7 | Gold          | 3       |
```

Sectors:

```
| id | name        |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | Equity      |
| 2  | Bonds       |
| 3  | Commodities |
```

So each subsector maps to a sector. This is reflected in my model classes.

I want to create a select box for subsectors with option groups with the sector name as the option group name and the child sectors as the options within. For Laravel's form builder I believe the following syntax is used:

```
{{ Form::select('subsector', array(
  'Equity' => [1 => 'Global Equity', 2 => 'US Equity', 3 => 'UK Equity'],
  'Bonds'  => [4 => 'Govt Bonds', 5 => 'IG Bonds', 6 => 'HY Bonds'],
  //etc...
))}}
```

My problem is writing the eloquent or fluent query to produce the nested array above to be passed to the formbuilder. I think I could do it by looping through an Eloquent query result object but I'd like to know if there's a nicer way to get a simple nested result of 2 joined tables.

All my relationships are defined in the models.

**Edit**

This method works but I was hoping for a cleaner way without nested `for` loops.

```
$subsectors = [];
$sectors = Sector::with('subsector')->get();
foreach ($sectors as $sector) 
{
    $subsectors[$sector->name] = [];
    foreach ($sector->subsector as $subsector)
    {
        $subsectors[$sector->name][$subsector->id] = $subsector->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Form::macro` so you can do this (I assume `subsectors` relation, for it's more accurate for `hasMany`):

```
$sectors = Sector::with('subsectors')->get();

Form::groupSelect('subsector', $sectors, 'subsectors')
```

and here goes the macro you need:

```
Form::macro(
    'groupSelect', 
    function ($name, $collection, $relation, $groupName = 'name', $optName = 'name', $optValue = 'id', $selected = null, $attributes = []) 
    {

        $groups = [];

        foreach ($collection as $model)
        {
            $groups[$model->$groupName] = $model->$relation->lists($optName, $optValue);
        }

        return Form::select($name, $groups, $selected, $attributes);
    }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of formulating a complex array in Controller, I would recommend doing this in your view by directly writing the HTML tag

```
<select name="subsector">
    @foreach(Sector::with('subsector')->get() as $sector)
        <optgroup label="{{ $sector->name }}">
        @foreach($sector->subsector as $subsector)
            <option value="{{ $subsector->id }}">{{{ $subsector->name }}}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Why is this a good idea? It results in more static messy code and doesn't support model form population and doesn't eliminate the need for nested for loops.